# ? sign create extra slashes in slugs in routes Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working in Laravel and facing an issue about creating route.

this is my blade file code kindly check anchor tags.

```html
<ul class=" dropdown-menu">
@foreach ($category as $categoryItem)
<li>
<a
href="{{ route('shop', ['slug' => $categoryItem->slug]) }}">
{{ $categoryItem->name }}
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>

@if ($categoryItem->subcategories->isNotEmpty())
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
@foreach ($categoryItem->subcategories as $subcategoryItem)
<li>
<a href="{{ route('shop', ['categorySlug' => $categoryItem->slug, 'slug' => $subcategoryItem->slug]) }}"
data-toggle="dropdown"
class="dropdown-toggle">{{ $subcategoryItem->name }}
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>

@if ($subcategoryItem->childcategory->isNotEmpty())
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
@foreach ($subcategoryItem->childcategory as $childCategoryItem)
<li>
<a
href="{{ route('shop', ['categorySlug' => $categoryItem->slug, 'subcategorySlug' => $subcategoryItem->slug, 'slug' => $childCategoryItem->slug]) }}">
{{ $childCategoryItem->name }}
</a>
</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@endif
</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@endif

</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

and this is route that i have created in web.php file

```html
Route::get('shop/{categorySlug?}/{subcategorySlug?}/{slug?}', [ShopController::class, 'shop'])->name('shop')->where(['categorySlug', 'subcategorySlug', 'slug' => '[\w\d\-]+(.*)']);
```

but with this code i am seeing floowing slugs for category, subcategory and child category respectively

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop///mens-fashion
http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/mens-fashion//men-clothes
http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/mens-fashion/men-clothes/t-shirt--shirts-
```

as you can see extra slashes are coming in category and sub-category slugs which is not good at all I need only one

how can i resolve this issue with route method?

Comment: you route parameters in blade file should be exactly same name as you have defined in route file.

Comment: they are same I've checked. you can also check

Comment: Your first link has route param as `'slug' => $categoryItem->slug`, try to change it to `categorySlug => $categoryItem->slug` like to defined in your second route. Route is mismatched with your route params

Comment: Similarly, in second route your second param should not be `'slug' => $subcategoryItem->slug` but it should be  `'subcategorySlug' => $subcategoryItem->slug,` like you did in third route.

Comment: thank you so much. it is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route parameters in blade file should be exactly same name as i have defined in route file

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are passing the wrong parameters to the calls to `route`:

To clearly demonstrate the error, see the following tinker output on your route:

```
❯ tnkr
Psy Shell v0.11.18 (PHP 8.1.19 — cli) by Justin Hileman
> route('shop')
= "http://site.test/shop"

> route('shop', ['categorySlug' => 'category'])
= "http://site.test/shop/category"

> route('shop', ['slug' => 'category'])
= "http://site.test/shop///category"
```

You need to update your route calls in the blade file to:

```
...
href="{{ route('shop', ['categorySlug' => $categoryItem->slug]) }}"
...
href="{{ route('shop', ['categorySlug' => $categoryItem->slug, 'subcategorySlug' => $subcategoryItem->slug]) }}"
...
href="{{ route('shop', ['categorySlug' => $categoryItem->slug, 'subcategorySlug' => $subcategoryItem->slug, 'slug' => $childCategoryItem->slug]) }}"
...
```

Optional parameters are only omitted when IT and ALL paremeters after it are also omitted. If you define a "more specific" parameter for example `slug`, but omit `subcategorySlug` or `categorySlug`, then they will be added to the url as `null`, and `(string) null === ''`.